# How can I handle the error "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile' in Python or Django?

Tags: python, django

Before explaining my problem in detail, here are my codes.

**models.py**

```
class SimilarStore(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

    domain = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SimilarStoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    similarstore_csv = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = SimilarStore
        fields = ('store', 'similarstore_csv')

    def save(self, commit=False, *args, **kwargs):
        form_input = SimilarStoreForm()

        self.store = self.cleaned_data['store']
        csv_file = self.cleaned_data['similarstore_csv']

        for line in csv_file:
            self.domain = line[0]
            self.score = line[1]
            self.rank = line[2]
            form_input.save()
```

**data.csv**

```
roolee.com,100,125225
piperandscoot.com,29.3,222166
calledtosurf.com,23.8,361542
cladandcloth.com,17.9,208670
neeseesdresses.com,9.6,251016
...
```

I'm trying to upload `data.csv` to DB. I need each column data in the file to go into `domain`, `score`, `rank` in `SimilarStore` model. This is what I'm trying to do with the above codes.

However, when I upload the file and submit it, an error shows up, saying

`expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile`

I've done some research about it, but nothing worked for my case. Can anyone figure out anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csv_file` is already a file; you don't need to open it. Just pass it straight to `csv.reader()`.

```
reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
```

Comment: That fixed the error, but it throws another error, `iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`. So, I searched about it and people say I need to try with another reading way like `r`, `rt`, or somthing like that, or set encoding. But, they need to be done in `open()`. Should I use `open()` again?

Comment: By the way, updated the `save()` part on the original past based on your first answer!

Answer (score 0):

When the file to read is already open, we have a problem, because of the fact that by removing the open line, we will obtain the following error.

> iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

I had the same error, and, to avoid it, I made(CSVfile is my CSV file which is already open):

```
decoded_file = CSVfile.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
reader = csv.reader(decoded_file, delimiter=delimitation)
```

Then, with that, I can pass into my CSVfile csv file by the loop:

```
for row in reader:
```

Comment: @Jae P. I think that it can resolve your issue