# How to fix "Iterators should return strings, not bytes" in Django File Upload

Tags: python, django, csv, file-upload

I'm trying to add an option to upload CSV files for one of my models in my Django App. I followed [this tutorial](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/import.html) to set it up but couldn't get it working. When uploading the file I get the following error:

**"_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)"**

This is a sample of the file I'm trying to upload:
https://pastebin.com/DMyudHav

I have already tried the following answers:
[How can I handle the error "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile' in Python or Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864199/how-can-i-handle-the-error-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-object-not-inmem?rq=1)

[Getting a TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299610/getting-a-typeerror-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-object-not-inmemoryuplo?rq=1)

My code looks like this right now:

```py
import csv
...

class AttendantsCSVForm(forms.Form):
    event = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Event.objects.all(), required=False)
    csv_file = forms.FileField()


class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def import_csv(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AttendantsCSVForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                event_id = request.POST.get('event')
                csv_file = request.FILES['csv_file']
                reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
                for row in reader:  # the error occurs here
                    for text in row:
                        print(text)
                self.message_user(request, _('CSV file imported successfully.'))
        form = AttendantsCSVForm()
        payload = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'admin/attendants_csv_form.html', payload)
```

How can I solve this? I've also read python's csv documentation but still can't find a solution to this problem.

I'm running the app on Windows, could that be the cause?

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704630/how-to-upload-and-read-csv-file-in-django-using-csv-dictreader) for more information.

I guess Jibu James's answer would work.

```
file = request.FILES['file'] 
decoded_file = file.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
reader = csv.DictReader(decoded_file)
for row in reader:
    # Get each cell value based on key-value pair. 
    # Key will always be what lies on the first row.
```